# "Reality shift" auf Deutsch

Tags: word-choice

Wie sagt man "reality shift" auf Deutsch? Also dass sich die Wahrnehmung der Wirklichkeit oder das Gefühl für sie (auf unklare oder schwer zu beschreibende Weise) verschoben hat.

Der Begriff "Realitätsverlust" ist seiner Bedeutung nach zwar inhaltlich richtig, die Vorstellung des Verlusts trifft die Sache aber nicht. Mir geht es um eine Veränderung der Wahrnehmung der Realität, nicht um deren Verlust. So wie ein "paradigm shift" eben auch kein Paradigmen*verlust* ist, sondern ein Paradigmen*wechsel*.

Comment: "Realitätsverlust" ist ein gebräuchliches Wort, aber wenn es Dir um die Nuance "verschoben" (vs. "verloren") geht, wäre das eventuell zu hart. Hast Du vielleicht ein Beispiel, um die angestrebte Verwendung klarer zu machen?

Comment: Hast du einen Satz? Das würde helfen (für's Gefühl)

Comment: Naja, das ist kein Beispiel für "reality shift" sondern für "shift". Hier würde ich einfach sagen "Etwas ist anders. Nichts hat sich verändert, alles ist wie immer, und doch.... "

Comment: Im icht literarischen Kontext würde ich "Verschiebung der Wahrnehmung" sagen.

Comment: *Verschwommene* Wahrnehmung? *Verzerrung* der Wahrnehmung?

Comment: Wenn es keinen Satz damit gibt, dann braucht man auch kein Wort. Dann musst du nach einem Weg fragen, dass Konzept auszudrücken, und solche Wege gibt es viele. Welcher der richtige ist, hängt hochgradid vom Kontext ab. Daher kann man die Frage dann leidr nicht allgemein beantworten sondern nur für diesen einen Beispielsatz. Und da würde eben genau keine der technischen Varianten passen, egal ob "Verschiebung" oder "Verlust" und "Realität" oder "Wahrnehmung"

Comment: Bitte nimm die Kommentare ernst und versuche, uns einen möglichst genauen **Kontext** für das in Frage stehende Wort zu geben. Mein Eindruck ist, dass du nur deshalb noch keine befriedingende Antwort erhalten hast. Danke schön!

Answer (score 3):

Klingt, als wolltest Du darauf hinaus, dass sich nicht so sehr die Realität aber stattdessen die Wahrnehmung der Realität ändert. Dementsprechend würde ich "veränderte Wahrnehmung" sagen.

Answer (score 1):

Für den geschilderten Fall ist [Derealisation](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derealisation) das richtige Wort, allerdings besitzt das nicht die Reichweite, die ich "Reality Shift" zugestehen würde.

Zusätzlich ist Derealisation wohl im Allgemeinen nicht gebräuchlich.

Comment: Ein medizinischer Begriff?

Comment: Aus der Psychologie, meine ich. Hier nur genannt, weil es das Beispiel recht genau trifft, nicht als Vorschlag zum täglichen Gebrauch.

Answer (score 0):

In dem von Dir genannten Kontext würde ich das mit "Wahrnehmungsverschiebung" oder "Wahrnehmungsänderung" übersetzen.